# Relation between low-rank approximation, nuclear norm of a matrix and Singular Value Decomposition

Tags: svd, matrix-decomposition

I'm reading the following paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.10203.pdf which proposes improvements on robustness of large graphs to defend against adversarial attacks that are nothing but slight perturbations on input graphs by introducing poisoned edges and nodes. Long story short, it has been observed that many real world graphs tend to be very sparse and low-rank, also they form local clusters with nodes having similar attributes (like friends on social networks).

So the authors propose a way to *recover* a *cleaned* adjacency matrix  by the following optimization schema:

\begin{equation}
arg \min_{S \in \mathcal{S}} \|A - F\|_F^2 + \alpha \|S\|_1 + \beta \|S\|_* \, \, \, s \,. \, t. \, \, S=S^T
\end{equation}

So here $A$ is the **poisoned** adjacency matrix, and since the adversarial attacks tend to be very unnoticeable, we want $F$ to be close to the input matrix $A$. By minimizing the $1$- norm and the $*$- norm we want to provide sparsity and low-rank respectively.

What I'd like to better figure out is the role of nuclear norm. It is defined as

$$\|A\|_*=\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(A)$$

i.e. it is the sum of the singular values of $A$. What is exactly the relation between having low rank and a low sum of singular values? I'm sure that it is about the singular value decomposition (SVD), a topic that I still have to clarify better.

Many thanks.,

James

Comment: so "mathematically" the rank is the count of the non zero singular values. $\sum _i|\sigma_i(A)|^0$